# proper __init__ definition in class inherited from "list"

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization

I'm trying to define "the good way" an init function for my class inherited from list. Here is the very basic code (I've kept the necessary only):

```
class measurementPoint(list) :
    """measurementPoint class : contains all the pairedMeasurement at a given temperature for a given channel"""

    def __init__(self, item):
        try:
            assert isinstance(item,pairedMeasurement)
        except AssertionError:
            print("Wrong type for object " + str(item))
            sys.exit(1)
        super().__init__(self)
        self.append(item)
```

Isn't there a better way to initialize such an object than `super().__init__` followed by an `append`? I guess there should be one but can't figure out how.

Comment: What are you trying to figure out? Can you please explain clearly.

Comment: Rather than `try: assert`, why not `if not isinstance(item, pairedMeasurement)`?

Comment: The only real problem with your code is that you're explicitly passing `self` to the `super` call. You're asking `list` to initialize itself from a copy of itself. In CPython 3.4, you happen to get lucky that instead of, say, going into an infinite loop, it just sees that `self`'s internal storage is empty and safely constructs a copy of nothing. But you'd be better off leaving it out.

Comment: OT but your typecheking using an `assert`, catching the `AssertionError`, printing a useless message and killing the whole process is just a major WTF. An unhandled exception WILL kill the process anyway, but at least it will print the full traceback, so you have much more informations about what went wrong (in your case you can at least know who passed the wrong item). TL;DR: remove the try/except, just keep the assert.

Comment: Also your initializer is not compatible with the parent's class one, which is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass item to `super().__init__` as an iterable:

```
>>> class A(list):
    def __init__(self, item):
        super().__init__([item])
...
>>> a = A(100)
>>> a
[100]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Probably the only combination I didn't try ^^.